# Unable to connect postgres database from rails application running inside WSL Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am running rail application inside WSL Ubuntu (20.04).
I have postgres server running inside docker on host machine.
Now I want my rails application to connect to the postgres database.
I have figured out the IP address of wsl using following command

```
 wsl -- ip -o -4 -json addr list eth0 `
| ConvertFrom-Json `
| %{ $_.addr_info.local } `
| ?{ $_ }
```

When I start my rails application, I get the following error.

```
/home/sm/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/foreman-0.61.0/lib/foreman/process.rb:69: warning: Insecure world writable dir /mnt/c in PATH, mode 040777
16:23:46 web.1  | started with pid 379
16:23:46 job.1  | started with pid 380
16:23:47 web.1  | I, [2023-08-28T16:23:47.365994 #381]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
16:23:59 web.1  | bundler: failed to load command: unicorn_rails (/home/sm/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/unicorn_rails)
16:23:59 web.1  | PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
16:23:59 web.1  |       Is the server running on host "169.254.170.20" and accepting
16:23:59 web.1  |       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Does anyone know how can rails application which is running inside WSL Ubuntu can access postgres server which is  running in docker of host machine.